# Installing ruby-1.9.3-p194 with rvm on OS X 10.8.5

Tags: ruby, rvm, osx-mountain-lion

I have installed the XCode command line developer tools, and installed `ruby-1.9.3-p448` and `ruby-2.0.0-p247` with out any trouble.

However, when I do `rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p194` I get an error:

```
Error running '__rvm_make -j 1',
please read /Users/michaelirey/.rvm/log/1382458979_ruby-1.9.3-p194/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Here is the output of that file:

```
[2013-10-22 09:23:22] __rvm_make
__rvm_make () 
{ 
    \make "$@" || return $?
}
current path: /Users/michaelirey/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194
command(3): __rvm_make -j 1
    CC = gcc
    LD = ld
    LDSHARED = gcc -dynamiclib
    CFLAGS = -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=pointer-arith -Werror=write-strings -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror=shorten-64-to-32 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fno-common -pipe 
    XCFLAGS = -include ruby/config.h -include ruby/missing.h -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT
    CPPFLAGS = -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin12.5.0 -I./include -I.
    DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -Wl,-flat_namespace -install_name /Users/michaelirey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib -current_version 1.9.1 -compatibility_version 1.9.1 -Wl,-unexported_symbol,_Init_* -Wl,-unexported_symbol,*_threadptr_*  -Wl,-u,_objc_msgSend   
    SOLIBS = 
compiling regparse.c
regparse.c:582:15: error: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'st_index_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Werror,-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    return t->num_entries;
    ~~~~~~ ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [regparse.o] Error 1
```

I have also tried:
`rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p194 --with-gcc=clang`

With the same result...

Answer (score 2):

Are you having in your environment `CC=gcc` - that would explain the problem - ruby 1.9.3 is not ready to build with it (or `clang`), make sure to unset it before trying:

```
rvm get stable              # always update rvm first in case of problems
unset CC                    # unset CC to allow autodetection to work 
rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p194 # do not add extra flags
```

This should allow RVM to autodetect proper GCC needed for thee given ruby to build, if it still fails it means you still have some environment preventing autodetection or there is a bug - open a bug report here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

Comment: Still seems to be an issue. I am opening a bug report.